# Hover on element and highlight all elements with the same class

Tags: css

I have many elements with the same class on a web page. I would like to highlight all these elements when I hover one of them. How can I do that in CSS?

Right now, I have this CSS:

```
p.un:hover { background-color:yellow;}
```

And my HTML:

```
<div class="book">
  <div class="page left">
    <p class="un">Karen…</p>
  </div>
   <div class="page right">
     <p class="un">Karen ne se retourne pas. Mme Tilford reste là, apparemment confuse et abattue.</p>
   </div>
```

Comment: You will need to use javascript..

Comment: CSS is mainly a parent -> child relationship. There are sibling selectors (http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/) but this will only work if the elements are at the same level, we need to see your setup.

Comment: The nested paragraph tags cannot trigger each other with just CSS in that setup. That would require javascript.

Comment: Where should I look for how to up the javascript?

Comment: I found a solution using JavaScript. See my answer to this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15960552/975097

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The best you can do using pure CSS is this:

```
.classname:hover ~ .classname {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

But this only highlights all siblings with a class `classname` **after** the hovered element.

You have to use JavaScript to highlight all elements;

```
var elms = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");
var n = elms.length;
function changeColor(color) {
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
        elms[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
for(var i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
    elms[i].onmouseover = function() {
        changeColor("yellow");
    };
    elms[i].onmouseout = function() {
        changeColor("white");
    };
}
```

If you have multiple classes and want to generalize this, use something like this:

```
var classes = ["one", "two", "three"]; //list of your classes
var elms = {};
var n = {}, nclasses = classes.length;
function changeColor(classname, color) {
    var curN = n[classname];
    for(var i = 0; i < curN; i ++) {
        elms[classname][i].style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
for(var k = 0; k < nclasses; k ++) {
    var curClass = classes[k];
    elms[curClass] = document.getElementsByClassName(curClass);
    n[curClass] = elms[curClass].length;
    var curN = n[curClass];
    for(var i = 0; i < curN; i ++) {
        elms[curClass][i].onmouseover = function() {
            changeColor(this.className, "yellow");
        };
        elms[curClass][i].onmouseout = function() {
            changeColor(this.className, "white");
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: Imagine how much people will be foaming in their mouths if the subject selector gets implemented: `!.classname ~ .classname:hover, .classname:hover ~ .classname` - well, perhaps not much at all.

Comment: It doesn't work. I put your code in a script tag : `<script type="text/javascript">
    var elms = document.getElementsByClassName("un");
var n = elms.length;
function changeColor(color) {
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
        elms[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
for(var i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
    elms[i].onmouseover = function() {
        changeColor("yellow");
    };
    elms[i].onmouseout = function() {
        changeColor("white");
    };
}
</script>`.

Comment: Do I need to use CSS with this setup?

Comment: @JustinD. Are you sure your `<script>` tag is **after** the definition of your `.un` elements? Just make sure it's in the bottom of `body`.

Comment: If I have many classnames (un, deux, trois, quatre, etc.), is there a quicker way to set the javascript than copying and changing the classname?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the answer from Chris. I used his code to write a simple function that does the job. You can place the function in the `<head></head>`  but you need to call it when the page has been loaded, i.e. place in the end of the body. colorout is the background-color

The function:

```
function hoverByClass(classname,colorover,colorout="transparent"){
    var elms=document.getElementsByClassName(classname);
    for(var i=0;i<elms.length;i++){
        elms[i].onmouseover = function(){
            for(var k=0;k<elms.length;k++){
                elms[k].style.backgroundColor="orange";//colorover;
            }
        };
        elms[i].onmouseout = function(){
            for(var k=0;k<elms.length;k++){
                elms[k].style.backgroundColor=colorout;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

and call the function like this:

```
hoverByClass("un","yellow");
hoverByClass("un2","pink");
```

I know the question is old, but maybe that help someone else :)

Try it here:

```js
function hoverByClass(classname,colorover,colorout="transparent"){
 var elms=document.getElementsByClassName(classname);
 for(var i=0;i<elms.length;i++){
  elms[i].onmouseover = function(){
   for(var k=0;k<elms.length;k++){
    elms[k].style.backgroundColor=colorover;
   }
  };
  elms[i].onmouseout = function(){
   for(var k=0;k<elms.length;k++){
    elms[k].style.backgroundColor=colorout;
   }
  };
 }
}
hoverByClass("un","yellow");
hoverByClass("un2","pink");
```

```html
<div class="book">
  <div class="page left">
    <p class="un">Karen…</p><p class="un2">Karen2…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="page right">
    <p class="un">Karen ne se retourne pas. Mme Tilford reste là, apparemment confuse et abattue.</p><p class="un2">Karen2 ne se retourne pas. Mme Tilford2 reste là, apparemment confuse et abattue.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In modern CSS, @Chris' answer may be improved upon to work without JavaScript code at all:

```css
html:has(.classname:hover) .classname {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

This works thanks to :has being applied to the root element, which is assumed to be `html` in this example.
It could also be `svg`, for instance.
Actually, it could even be just about any selector, for instance to only apply the highlighting to parts of a document contained in the elements matched by this selector.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .highlight {
        background-color: yellow;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        const un = document.querySelectorAll(".un");
        un.forEach((el) => {
          el.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
            un.forEach((el) => {
              el.classList.add("highlight");
            });
          });
          el.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
            un.forEach((el) => {
              el.classList.remove("highlight");
            });
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="book">
      <div class="page left">
        <p class="un">Karen…</p>
      </div>
      <div class="page right">
        <p class="un">
          Karen ne se retourne pas. Mme Tilford reste là, apparemment confuse et
          abattue.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="page right">
        <p class="un">Another paragraph with the same class.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).