# Highlight all elements with same class when one of them is moused over

Tags: javascript, html

In JavaScript, is it possible to highlight all items with the same class when one of them is moused over?

For example, if I had two paragraphs with the class `p1` and 2 paragraphs with the class `p2`, I'd want both elements of `p1` to be highlighted on mouseover, and I'd also want both elements of p2 to be highlighted on mouseover.

```
<p class = "p1">This should be highlighted on mouseover</p>
<p class = "p2">This should be highlighted on mouseover</p>
<p class = "p1">This should be highlighted on mouseover</p>
<p class = "p2">This should be highlighted on mouseover</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't help but feel this *should* be more concise (the use of *three* `for (...)` loops feels unnecessarily expensive), but one approach:

```
Object.prototype.classHighlight = function (over, out) {
    var that = this.length ? this : [this];
    function onOver() {
        for (var i = 0, len = that.length; i < len; i++) {
            that[i].style.backgroundColor = over;
        }
    }
    function onOut() {
        for (var i = 0, len = that.length; i < len; i++) {
            that[i].style.backgroundColor = out;
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0, len = that.length; i < len; i++) {
        that[i].onmouseover = onOver;
        that[i].onmouseout = onOut;
    }
};

document.getElementsByClassName('test').classHighlight('#f90', '#fff');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5mmYR/).

Six years later, following a link to this question and answer, I'm editing to update the above approach, and to add snippets and references.

Updated code:

```js
// extending the Object prototype to allow chaining of this method,
// 'over' : String, the class-name to add when the element(s) of the
// HTMLCollection/NodeList are hovered-over. We also set the default
// value of the 'over' variable in order that a class-name will always
// be present:
Object.prototype.classHighlight = function(over = 'over') {

  // taking the 'this' and using the spread operator to expand
  // the iterable collection to an Array:
  const that = [...this],

    // creating a named function to act as the event-handler for
    // 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave':
    toggleHighlight = (event) => {
      // iterating over the array using Array.prototype.forEach():
      that.forEach(

        // we're not using 'this' in here, so using an Arrow function
        // to use the Element.classList API to toggle the supplied
        // class on each element of the collection. If the event-type
        // is exactly equal to 'mouseenter' we add the class otherwise
        // we remove the class:
        (el) => el.classList.toggle(over, event.type === 'mouseenter')
      );
    };
  // iterating over the collection, again using Array.prototype.forEach():
  that.forEach(
    // and another Arrow function:
    (element) => {

      // here we bind the toggleHighlight function - created above - as
      // the event-handler for both the 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave'
      // events:
      element.addEventListener('mouseenter', toggleHighlight);
      element.addEventListener('mouseleave', toggleHighlight);
    });
};

// here we use document.getElementsByClassName() to retrieve an HTMLCollection
// of elements matching the supplied class-name; and then using chaining - which
// is why we extended the Object prototype - to pass that HTMLCollection to
// the classHighlight() function:
document.getElementsByClassName('test').classHighlight('whenOver');
```

```css
.whenOver {
  background-color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<p class="test">Testing</p>
<div>No classes here</div>
<ul>
  <li class="test">Something in a 'test' element</li>
</ul>
```

Note that this updated approach, because we're toggling a class-name – as opposed to adding and clearing inline styles in the elements' `style` attribute – means that selector-specificity may interfere with application of the style, for example:

```js
// extending the Object prototype to allow chaining of this method,
// 'over' : String, the class-name to add when the element(s) of the
// HTMLCollection/NodeList are hovered-over. We also set the default
// value of the 'over' variable in order that a class-name will always
// be present:
Object.prototype.classHighlight = function(over = 'over') {

  // taking the 'this' and using the spread operator to expand
  // the iterable collection to an Array:
  const that = [...this],

    // creating a named function to act as the event-handler for
    // 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave':
    toggleHighlight = (event) => {
      // iterating over the array using Array.prototype.forEach():
      that.forEach(

        // we're not using 'this' in here, so using an Arrow function
        // to use the Element.classList API to toggle the supplied
        // class on each element of the collection. If the event-type
        // is exactly equal to 'mouseenter' we add the class otherwise
        // we remove the class:
        (el) => el.classList.toggle(over, event.type === 'mouseenter')
      );
    };
  // iterating over the collection, again using Array.prototype.forEach():
  that.forEach(
    // and another Arrow function:
    (element) => {

      // here we bind the toggleHighlight function - created above - as
      // the event-handler for both the 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave'
      // events:
      element.addEventListener('mouseenter', toggleHighlight);
      element.addEventListener('mouseleave', toggleHighlight);
    });
};

// here we use document.getElementsByClassName() to retrieve an HTMLCollection
// of elements matching the supplied class-name; and then using chaining - which
// is why we extended the Object prototype - to pass that HTMLCollection to
// the classHighlight() function:
document.getElementsByClassName('test').classHighlight('whenOver');
```

```css
li.test {
  background-color: fuchsia;
}
.whenOver {
  background-color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<p class="test">Testing</p>
<div>No classes here</div>
<ul>
  <li class="test">Something in a 'test' element</li>
</ul>
```

This can be resolved by increasing the selector specificity of the assigned class-name:

```
li.test {
  background-color: fuchsia;
}

html body .whenOver {
  background-color: #f90;
}
```

```js
Object.prototype.classHighlight = function(over = 'over') {

  const that = [...this],

    toggleHighlight = (event) => {
      that.forEach(
        (el) => el.classList.toggle(over, event.type === 'mouseenter')
      );
    };
  that.forEach(
    (element) => {
      element.addEventListener('mouseenter', toggleHighlight);
      element.addEventListener('mouseleave', toggleHighlight);
    });
};

document.getElementsByClassName('test').classHighlight('whenOver');
```

```css
li.test {
  background-color: fuchsia;
}

html body .whenOver {
  background-color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<p class="test">Testing</p>
<div>No classes here</div>
<ul>
  <li class="test">Something in a 'test' element</li>
</ul>
```

Or, you could instead use the `!important` keyword to force that `!important`-ified property to apply regardless of specificity (unless another rule also uses `!important` and is itself more specific), for example:

```
/* Note the ridiculous and overly-specific selector: */
html > body > ul > li.test {
  background-color: fuchsia;
}

.whenOver {
  / and here, as the demo shows, !important still
    wins: */
  background-color: #f90 !important;
}
```

```js
Object.prototype.classHighlight = function(over = 'over') {

  const that = [...this],

    toggleHighlight = (event) => {
      that.forEach(
        (el) => el.classList.toggle(over, event.type === 'mouseenter')
      );
    };
  that.forEach(
    (element) => {
      element.addEventListener('mouseenter', toggleHighlight);
      element.addEventListener('mouseleave', toggleHighlight);
    });
};

document.getElementsByClassName('test').classHighlight('whenOver');
```

```css
html > body > ul > li.test {
  background-color: fuchsia;
}

.whenOver {
  background-color: #f90 !important;
}
```

```html
<p class="test">Testing</p>
<div>No classes here</div>
<ul>
  <li class="test">Something in a 'test' element</li>
</ul>
```

When it comes to `!important`, though, try to avoid using it wherever possible because, as MDN notes:

> Using `!important`, however, is bad practice and should be avoided because it makes debugging more difficult by breaking the natural [cascade] in your stylesheets.
>
> <sub>"[The `!important` exception](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception)," MDN</sub>.

References:

- CSS:

  - [Selector specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception).
    *JavaScript:
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).
  - [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: You can also highlight multiple classes using a single function, as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/5mmYR/1/

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/aZXRM/) (which requires JQuery). When a member of `p1` is moused over, all other elements of `p1` will be highlighted as well. The same is true of `p2`.

JavaScript:

```
function highlightAllOnMouseover(className){
    $(className).mouseover(function() {
  $(className).css("opacity", 0.4); 
  $(className).css("opacity", 1);
}).mouseleave(function() { 
    $(className).css("opacity", 0.4);
});
}
highlightAllOnMouseover(".thing1");
highlightAllOnMouseover(".thing2");
```

HTML:

```
<p class = "thing1">This is thing1.</p>
<p class = "thing2">This is thing2.</p>
<p class = "thing1">This is also thing1.</p>
<p class = "thing2">This is also thing2.</p>
```

To cause all elements with a specific class to be highlighted on mouseover, you only need to call the function `highlightAllOnMouseover(className)`, which I created here.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a zero-dependency solution that should work with very old JS versions:

1. Add `class = 'grp_N hovergrp'` to all elements that should be highlighted on hover, replacing `N` by some number (or id) that uniquely describes a group of elements. The groups may not intersect, every element with `hovergrp` class should belong to exactly one `grp_N` class.
2. Append the following `JS` snippet in a `<script>...</script>` to the end of your `<html>`:

```js
  // collect all highlighted elements and group them by their group 
  // name for faster access;
  // Attach onmouseover and onmouseout listeners.
  var groups = {};
  var hovergrp = document.getElementsByClassName("hovergrp"); 
  for (var i = 0; i < hovergrp.length; i++) {
    var e = hovergrp.item(i);
    var eClasses = e.classList;
    for (var j = 0; j < eClasses.length; j++) {
      var c = eClasses[j];
      if (c.startsWith("grp_")) {
        if (!groups[c]) {
          groups[c] = [];
        }
        groups[c].push(e);
        e.onmouseover = (function(c_capture) {
          return function(_event) {
            highlightGroup(c_capture, "orange");
          };
        })(c);
        e.onmouseout = (function(c_capture) {
          return function(_event) {
            highlightGroup(c_capture, "transparent");
          };
        })(c);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  
  function highlightGroup(groupName, color) {
    var g = groups[groupName];
    for (var i = 0; i < g.length; i++) {
      g[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
  }
```

```html
  <pre><code>
    // hover over variable names `<span class='grp_0 hovergrp'>x</span>` and `<span class='grp_1 hovergrp'>f</span>`
    kroneckerDelta(<span class='grp_0 hovergrp'>x</span>) {
      return function(<span class='grp_1 hovergrp'>f</span>) {
        <span class='grp_1 hovergrp'>f</span>(<span class='grp_0 hovergrp'>x</span>)
      }
    }
  </code></pre>

<p class = "grp_p1 hovergrp">This should be highlighted on mouseover</p>
<p class = "grp_p2 hovergrp">This should be highlighted on mouseover</p>
<p class = "grp_p1 hovergrp">This should be highlighted on mouseover</p>
<p class = "grp_p2 hovergrp">This should be highlighted on mouseover</p>
```

The HTML snippet shows usage example: a little `<pre>`-formatted snippet of code with variables that are grouped into two groups. Whenever you hover over a variable, all the usages of the variable as well as the binding site are highlighted.