# How to highlight all matched elements when hover each of them?

Tags: html, css, highlight

I am referenced with [Highlight all elements with same class when one of them is moused over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960544/highlight-all-elements-with-same-class-when-one-of-them-is-moused-over)

The way I wanted to know is - Is it possible with CSS?

I am trying with `sibling: ~` but it can't highlight previous sibling elements.

```css
.test {
  color: blue;
}
.test:hover, .test:hover ~ .test {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="prev">Test Highlight by mouse over the `blue` texts: </span>
  <span class="test">This </span>
  <span class="test">Is </span>
  <span class="test">The </span>
  <span class="test">Highlight</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't, as you've found - because CSS selectors lack the ability to traverse backwards through the cascade - possible with CSS; but thank you for prompting me to update an answer I'd entirely forgotten about until now.

Comment: Thanks @DavidThomas, so the only the solution is to use `javascript`, right?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes (CSS [selectors level 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/) has a proposed relational pseudo-class [`:has()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#relational) that *may* allow for this, but it seems unlikely to make it into browsers in the early days of Selectors level 4.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i am aware this is not possible because CSS as of right now is unable to select any preceding elements, though you can achieve this kind of behaviour doing something like this:

```css
.test {
  color: blue;
}
.x:hover .test {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<span class="prev">Test Highlight by mouse over the `blue` texts: </span>
<span class="x">
  <span class="test">This </span>
  <span class="test">Is </span>
  <span class="test">The </span>
  <span class="test">Highlight</span>
</span>
```

You can read more about CSS being unable to select previous elements [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector)

Comment: if I can wrap `span`s into one parent element then I don't need this question. And answer is much simple than yours - `x:hover { color: red; }`

Comment: ```x:hover > span { color: red; }```* but yeah, there is not much to it either that or JS