# How do I make all items in a list except one hover?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make it so that when you hover over the navbar, every item EXCEPT the home button momentarily has a background of orange. I then tried adding a specific class to the list item with the home button while listing it with greater specificity in the css and that didn't work. I tried adding a specific class to every list item in the nav bar other than the one with the home button and simply listing the styling properties for that hover while deleting all of my other rules for hover buttons. What can I do to turn the hover off for the home button? I don't wanna take it away from the list because then, it throws off the entire alignment of the header. Here is my code. https://github.com/chawalk90/padibilityweb

Comment: please try to isolate your problem, and paste it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: you can do better than that give a fiddle demo with problem

Comment: Put the relevant code in your question please.

Answer (score 1):

### PURE CSS Based Solution

### [Check Demo selecting individual elements](http://jsfiddle.net/sachindivakar/85e5nnb4/)

### [This Demo Show Specific element being omitted](http://jsfiddle.net/sachindivakar/85e5nnb4/2/)

### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>First child</li>
      <li>second child</li>
      <li>third child</li>
      <li>fourth child</li>
      <li>fifth child</li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
li{

    list-style:none;
}
ul li:nth-child(1):hover {  
  color: #ac5;
}
ul li:nth-child(2):hover {  
  color: #eb2;
}
ul li:nth-child(3):hover {  
  color: #1e1;
}
ul li:nth-child(4):hover {  
  color: #43f;
}
ul li:nth-child(5):hover{  
  color: #1ee;
}
```

> The Case you asked

### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>First child</li>
      <li>second child's color does not change on hover</li>
      <li>third child</li>
      <li>fourth child</li>
      <li>fifth child</li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
li{

    list-style:none;
}
ul li:not(:nth-child(2)):hover {  
  color: red;
}

ul li:nth-child(2) {  
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Demo links to jsFiddle home page.

Comment: @DJDavid98 i think i copied the link address before it changed after saving fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I would use JavaScript for this. [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786810/css-hover-on-element-and-highlight-all-with-same-class)

```
`var classes = ["one", "two", "three"]; //list of your classes
var elms = {};
var n = {}, nclasses = classes.length;
function changeColor(classname, color) {
    var curN = n[classname];
    for(var i = 0; i < curN; i ++) {
        elms[classname][i].style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
for(var k = 0; k < nclasses; k ++) {
    var curClass = classes[k];
    elms[curClass] = document.getElementsByClassName(curClass);
    n[curClass] = elms[curClass].length;
    var curN = n[curClass];
    for(var i = 0; i < curN; i ++) {
        elms[curClass][i].onmouseover = function() {
            changeColor(this.className, "yellow");
        };
        elms[curClass][i].onmouseout = function() {
            changeColor(this.className, "white");
        };
    }
};`
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/na04ya3f/
The CSS works for all modern browsers,

### CSS

```
ul, ul li{

   transition:all 1.5s;

    color:black;

}

ul:hover li:not(:first-child){

   background-color:orange; 

}
```

### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Not Home</li>
    <li>Not Home</li>
</ul>
```